# Angular dynamic validation based on selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm developing a mobile application with ionic framework and angularJS. Now I got problem when working on dynamic validation.

This is my form, I try to set validation value from controller when select box changed, but it won't work.

```
<form id="my-form" ng-submit="submit(form,request)" name="form" novalidate>
  <div ng-class="{'has-error':form.biller-name.$invalid}">
    <span>Biller</span>
    <select id="biller" name="biller-name" ng-model="request.biller" ng-change="getValidationAmount(request.biller)" required>
        <option value="">Choose biller name</option>
      <option value="BA">Biller A</option>
      <option value="BB">Biller B</option>
        <option value="BC">Biller C</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-show="form.biller-name.$invalid && form.biller-name.$dirty">
        <p ng-if="form.biller-name.$error.required">Biller name must be chosen</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-class="{'has-error':form.amount.$invalid}">
    <span>Amount</span>
    <input name="amount" ng-model="request.amount" type="number" ui-number-mask="2" max="{{billerVal.maxAmount}}" min="{{billerVal.minAmount}}" required/>

    <div ng-show="form.amount.$invalid && form.amount.$dirty">
            <p ng-if="form.amount.$invalid">validation works</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input value="Submit" id="login_btnSubmit" data-role="button"
    data-shadow="false" type="submit"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

My JS, have two function. first to get data from db, and the update function will be update validation on the page.

```
$scope.getValidationAmount = function (data){

  //get data from db
  beneficiaryService.getAmountByBenefeciaryType(JSON.parse(data)).then(function(amount){

    var amountSplitLast2Character = amount.substr(amount.length - 2);
    var firstCharacter = amount.substr(0, (amount.length - amountSplitLast2Character.length));
    $scope.bill.amount = firstCharacter+'.'+amountSplitLast2Character;

    //will do update function
    $scope.update(JSON.parse(data).nickname);
  },function(data,opt,error){});
};

$scope.update = function(nickname) {

  var billerVal = {};

  //this code below just for get object biller by nickname
  for(var i in billerList) {
    if (billerList[i].nickname == nickname) {
      for(var j in billerEnumList) {
        if (billerEnumList[j].key == billerList[i].name) {
          billerVal = billerEnumList[j];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  billerVal.maxAmount = parseInt(billerVal.maxAmount); //will return a number of amount e.g 100
  billerVal.minAmount = parseInt(billerVal.minAmount); //will return a number of amount e.g 1
  $scope.billerVal = billerVal; //set validation value to html page
}
```

When I hard coded validation for min and max value in html directly the validation works properly.
But, when I try to use dynamic validation like code above, the validation won't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple custom validation directive as a **workaround** for this particular condition displayed in [this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/AG2wf/393/).

There are issues related to it in angular official Github Repo.

```
app.directive('ngMin', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngMin, function () {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
            var minValidator = function (value) {
                var min = scope.$eval(attr.ngMin) || 0;
                if (!isEmpty(value) && value < min) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('ngMin', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('ngMin', true);
                    return value;
                }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(minValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(minValidator);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('ngMax', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngMax, function () {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
            var maxValidator = function (value) {
                var max = scope.$eval(attr.ngMax) || Infinity;
                if (!isEmpty(value) && value > max) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', true);
                    return value;
                }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(maxValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(maxValidator);
        }
    };
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why create a directive? min and max is already a built in directive from the core angular as stated in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

Comment: Because its a bug that angular do not watches these built in directives after it is rendered dynamically.There are issues related to it in angular official github repo. So this is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you @mJunaidSalaat will try to use your directive and will mark as accepted aswer after all work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use interpolation syntax to indicate the min and max length in the view. You could directly use the $scope property.

```
<input name="amount" ng-model="request.amount" type="number" ui-number-mask="2" max="billerVal.maxAmount" min="billerVal.minAmount" required/>
```

Comment: It wouldn't work. with interpolation syntax I got the value filled to the min and max value, but not without it.

Comment: Are you sure that the billerVal object is being populated correctly?

Comment: Sure, this is with interpolation syntax [http://postimg.org/image/5bl2vctkp/](http://postimg.org/image/5bl2vctkp/) and this one without [http://postimg.org/image/aa3zw57zt/](http://postimg.org/image/aa3zw57zt/)

Comment: Where is the interpolation in the 1st image? interpolation is {{}}. Of course on the first image it will work as you've hard coded the actual value. If I were you, try to display the billerVal object in the view for you to see the actual values when the update() function is called.

Comment: yes I know the interpolation is {{}}.
at the first image that is syntax using interpolation, and when I change select box, it will populate by self data from update function.
but no if I don't use interpolation.